# Scipy box cox plot function not showing plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I run this code.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,15))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)

prob = sp.stats.probplot(var, dist=sp.stats.norm, plot=ax1)
ax1.set_xlabel('')
ax1.set_title('Probplot against normal distribution')
```

It works totally fine and I get this as the output.

[image]

However when I try running the box_cox_normality plot , it is not generating any graph

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
lamdas,ppc=sp.stats.boxcox_normplot(var, -20, 20, plot=ax)
```

I get this.

[image]

I am not sure why it is not plotting. I am using ipython matplotlib inline so don't need to do plt.show()

Advise pls

**Edit:**

I am not sure if the problem is in data. The problem is unless I do 
plt.plot(arg) explicitly it is not plotting.

Here is an example. Pls note that there is no missing value in this variable as that has been taken care of.

Here is the code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
lamdas,ppc=sp.stats.boxcox_normplot(var, -20, 20, plot=ax)
#plt.plot(lamdas,ppc)
max_ppc=lamdas[ppc.argsort()[::-1][0]]
ax.axvline(lamdas[ppc.argsort()[::-1][0]],color='b')
y, lmax_mle = sp.stats.boxcox(var)
lmax_pearsonr = sp.stats.boxcox_normmax(var)
ax.axvline(lmax_mle, color='r')
ax.axvline(lmax_pearsonr, color='g', ls='--')
print max_ppc,lmax_mle,lmax_pearsonr
```

The boxcox norm plot should work on its own as it takes a plot=ax parameter. But it gives the following plot which clearly doesn't print the boxcox plot. Check that plt.plot() is commented out.

[image]

Now I run the same code with plt.plot() statement uncommented.

[image]

As you see it plots the complete plot. So somewhere something went wrong that now it needs explicit plt.plot statement to plot. BoxCox is doing the transformation right. Earlier I didn't see such a problem

Comment: Does `var` contain any NaNs or infinite values?

Comment: Similar to ali_m's comment: perhaps the transformation failed? Since boxcox_normplot returns the lambdas for which the transformation was done, you may want to check the return values of the plot.

Comment: the return wvalue generated is fine. I can see all the values of lamas.But it doesn't plot

Comment: I suspect this might be data-dependent, any chance you can share the actual data?

Comment: I had the same thing happening. Sometimes it would plot and sometimes it wouldn't.
Thanks for mentioning the `plt.plot()`, that always makes sure it works.